# function name with on+Verb in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I noticed in UI5 there are a lot of functions named with on+verb.
for example:

```
sap.Panel.prototype.onPressButton = function (oEvent) {
   //.....
};
```

does it imply the function is related to the Event bus. where I could find the reference for this type of function in UI5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its only a convention to distinguish 'event callbacks' function from 'other functions'.

Same as set / get for setters & getters